# error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Float

Tags: java

Why do I get

error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Float

in the following method?

```java
bmi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Float weightKg,heightmeter1,heightmeter2,TotalHeight,BMI;

        String sweight = kg.getText().toString();
        weightKg = Float.parseFloat(sweight);

        String sfeet = feet.getText().toString();
        float heightFeet = Float.parseFloat(sfeet);
        heightmeter1 =  heightFeet *0.3048;

        String sinch = inch.getText().toString();
        float heightInch = Float.parseFloat(sinch);
        heightmeter2 =heightInch*0.0254;

        TotalHeight = heightmeter1+heightmeter2;

        BMI = weightKg + (TotalHeight*TotalHeight);

       displaybmi.setText(" Your BMI Is = "+BMI+"  ");

    }
});
```

Android Studio show me that in Build output

```
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Social_Media\app\src\main\java\com\example\social_media\MainActivity.java:73: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Float
        heightmeter1 =  heightFeet *0.3048;
                                   ^
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Social_Media\app\src\main\java\com\example\social_media\MainActivity.java:77: error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Float
        heightmeter2 =heightInch*0.0254;
                                ^
```

Comment: `float feetConst = 0.3048f, inchConst = 0.0254f;` then use: `heightmeter1 =  (heightFeet * feetConst); heightmeter2 = (heightInch * inchConst);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java a floating point literal without a type suffix is always interpreted as a `double`.

You need to add the `f` suffix like this:

```java
heightmeter1 = heightFeet * 0.3048f;
...
heightmeter2 = heightInch * 0.0254f;
```